# Issue in creating .icns

Tags: objective-c

I have created icns file using IconFamily, but after creating the image the quality of image is bad. Is there any other alternative to create icns image in Mac.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478925/objective-c-convert-an-image-to-icns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ImageIO.framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/) can write ICNS files.

Create a [CGImageDestinationRef](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageDestination/).  Add a [CGImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/) for each of the bitmaps you'd like in the ICNS file.  Finalize the CGImageDestination.

Comment: @Sri I am stuck in the same error. Can you please post the code for the same ?