# Objective-C - Convert an image to icns

Tags: objective-c, image, macos, operating-system

I am trying to create an app for the Mac OS X that will convert an image type to an icns file. I'm wondering how I can get started on doing so. Any suggestions would be nice!

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: What's wrong with Icon Composer? All you have to do is paste the image into its spot.

Comment: Icon Composer. It's part of XCode.

Comment: I have to do it programmically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CGImageSource APIs (e.g., `CGImageSourceCreateWithURL`, `CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex`) to load each image into a `CGImageRef`.  Then use CGImageDestination APIs (e.g., `CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL`, `CGImageDestinationAddImage`, `CGImageDestinationFinalize`) to combine however many images you have into one icon file.  The 3rd parameter of `CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL` would be `kUTTypeAppleICNS`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely look into those APIs

Comment: "`CGImageDestination`, produces buggy ICNS files in pre 10.7 (maybe pre 10.6.8)." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27808025/how-to-progrmatically-make-mac-os-x-icns-with-10-differnt-images-using-sips-or-o/27809425#comment44029912_27809425

Answer (score 1):

1 Create a folder named `icon.iconset`.
 2 Add one or more of the following images to the folder:

```
icon_16x16.png
icon_16x16@2x.png
icon_32x32.png
icon_32x32@2x.png
icon_128x128.png
icon_128x128@2x.png
icon_256x256.png
icon_256x256@2x.png
icon_512x512.png
icon_512x512@2x.png
```

3 Run this command and `icon.icns` will be created.

```
iconutil -c icns icon.iconset
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Optimizing/Optimizing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012302-CH7-SW2

Answer (score 0):

Save the NSImage which contains the icon as a TIFF file (use `NSData* tiff = [image TIFFRepresentation];` to create a NSData with the TIFF file, and then just use `[tiff writeToFile:tiffFile atomically:YES];` to save it in some folder), then use NSTask to convert the TIFF file to an ICNS file using `tiff2icns`.

```
tiff2icns /Users/Me/Desktop/pic.tiff /Users/Me/Desktop/pic.icns
```

Now, an example of the complete code (image is a NSImage file the icon, and iconFile is an NSString with the final location of the icns):

```
    NSString* tiffFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.tiff",iconFile];

    NSData* tiff = [image TIFFRepresentation];
    [tiff writeToFile:tiffFile atomically:YES];

    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/tiff2icns"];

    [task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:tiffFile, iconFile, nil]];
    [task launch];
    [task waitUntilExit];

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:tiffFile error: NULL];
```

And that's it.